# Avatar maker w/ XML/AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

So I have another question related to this one but I wanted to ask some general advice on the best way to go about this. I'm trying to make an avatar creator, which grabs elements from an XML file (head, hair, eyes, nose mouth, etc) and overlays them on top of each other.

I'm rather new to actionscript, so what I did was just follow a bunch of xml photo gallery tutorials and examples and sort of mended it to my needs, which probably wasn't the best way to go from the start but I learned a lot from it.

Here's currently what it looks like: **i.imgur.com/HRxNi.jpg**
There's a scrollpane element which  thumbnails get loaded into, a combo box to switch between elements, and a save button that does nothing as of now, but eventually I'll want it to send what's on the stage to my server and let php save it as an avvie.

Basically what I've accomplished is getting the thumbs to load for one element (the head) and you can click between them to change them, and nothing more than that.

What I need to do and what I would like advice on is

*(1) getting different thumbs to load for different elements as per the combobox (e.g. "hair" is chosen from combo box, and hair options show up in the scroll pane)*

*(2) When a hair element or whatever element is clicked it layers over whatever is underneath it*

Here's what I've got so far, three as files included to my project doing all the work, you can view them here : http://pastebin.com/Jy9HPNWH (pasted all three files in there, commented it so you know what's happening)

And my XML file you can view here: http://pastebin.com/nbAUryUk so that's the structure im using

Any ideas on how to do this in the best way possible? I'm really at a roadblock where I'm at, it seems simple in theory but I'm new to the AS scene maybe some of you guys have better ideas

I'm sure I could accomplish this in a very procedural manner but that just seems like a coding sin to me.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**Getting different thumbs to load for different elements as per the combobox (e.g. "hair" is chosen from combo box, and hair options show up in the scroll pane.**

Break the things down in two levels. Categories and Items. The categories holds it own detail (e.g categoryName = "hair" , categoryId = 1, categoryImage = "cat-hair.jpg")

Now create Items all items know which category they belong to. When a category is click search for items with the same category ID. now you have your items.

Create one box who you pass the Item details to (image url, category id etc etc) it independantly loads the jpeg of the item.

When the user clicks on this box. Use the Id to load the item on the preview pane.

**When a hair element or whatever element is clicked it layers over whatever is underneath it**

myMan.addChild(loadedHairDisplayObject)

But here is the thing. You will need to keep a check on layers (if you have big hair that cover eye etc). That the hair are always over eyes. The eyebrows are always over the eyes and so on and everything is placed inside that perticular layer. Do this only if you have items that cover something over them otherwise you're good.

Comment: thanks your first suggestion helped me a lot, still a little confused on layering, i might just use conditional statements..